# Install Xubuntu on two hard drives

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

I have a laptop with two hard drives and I would like to install Xubuntu.

Here are the two hard drives:

***256GB SSD and
500GB HDD***

Can I install The / and /home partitions on the SSD one and again a /home partition on the whole 500GB hard drive (HDD hard drive)
During the installation, it is written that I need to create a partition for grub2core.img. How many MB does it need?

Comment: LVM provides a method of allocating space on mass-storage devices that is more flexible than conventional partitioning schemes. In particular, a volume manager can concatenate, stripe together or otherwise combine partitions into larger virtual ones that administrators can resize or move, potentially without interrupting system use. Would it be OK to use LVM to span the `/home` partition across multiple drives by creating a logical volume for `/home`? `/home` would be located on a single logical volume that spans part of the SSD and all of the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu doesn’t use a separate `/home` partition by default and all the Linux directory are stored on the same partition. But there is one benefit of using a separate `home` partition: It allows you to reinstall Ubuntu without losing your personal files.

While Installing Ubuntu, choose the “Something Else” installation option to use a custom partition layout and create multiple partitions. Set the mount point for one of your partitions as `/`  which will contain the root file system – and another mount point of another partition as /home
[image]

Comment: Yes but can I install two /home partitions. One on the SSD hard drive and another one on the HDD hard drive?

Comment: No. Since the directory structure is fixed for all systems using Linux. Therefore every user has only one home directory. But a user can own as many other directories as you want. Ex. You can create an empty directory, and specify the write permissions to a directory `/home/otherdir`, then use the command:  `mkdir /home/otherdir` and `chown myuser /home/otherdir`

Comment: OK. Can I do this? I install / and /home partitions on SSD hard drive and I create a partition ext4 on the HDD hard drive. Then after the installation, I specify the permissions to this partition ext4 with the command chown myuser.